# Controlling -webkit-mask polygon with JavaScript not working on iOs

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html

I am trying to control a polygon mask with javascript.
On Chrome it works perfectly.
On iOs (intel xdk) it just shows the mask from the inline-HTML part, the Javascript seems not to change anything there.
(No jQuery)

```js
   function $(id)
{
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

//[...]

function Bar(BarWert)  //BarWert are Numbers between 0 and 100
{
    var XP = localStorage.XPmain; //Here are numbers saved

    BarWert = Number(BarWert) + 1;

    opa = ((BarWert / 2) + 49) / 100;
        
    var toGoal = BarWert * 0.86;

    if (XP == 0)
        {
            $("HomeXPBar").style = "opacity: " + opa + ";-webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 100%, 50% 87%, 90% 100%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%);";
        }
        else
        {
            $("HomeXPBar").style =
                "opacity: " + opa
                + ";-webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% "
                + (100 - toGoal) 
                + "%, 50% " 
                + (87 - toGoal) 
                + "%, 90% " 
                + (100 - toGoal) 
                + "%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%);";
        }
 }
```

```css
    #HomeXPBar {
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
 height: 110%;
 top: -1%;
 right: 50%;
 z-index: 2;
 }
```

```html
    <img id="HomeXPBar" src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="-webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 48%, 50% 35%, 90% 48%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%);">
```

Comment: What is `$` if it's not jQuery? And what is `XP`?

Comment: Oh, at the beginning of my JS I have:
'function $(id)
    {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }'

Comment: XP, opa and toGoal are numbered Variables.
As I said, that code works in Chrome, just not on iOs.

Comment: And what is `$` ? It sure looks like jQuery.

Comment: 'function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }'

Comment: `clip-path` is not supported by all browsers yet, so I that might be the problem here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility

Comment: The thing is, in the ios the clippath that is in the html works fine. it just is not influenced by the js as intended.